# How to show list view choosed images in gallery android?

Tags: android, android-listview, image-gallery

I am using list view and gallery in android.. i have 3 views as  list items i.e a contact photo,name and a button to add that contact . when user clicks the button inside list view,the contact photo of that items should add in gallery... Can anybody please tell how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, Why can't you just download the image and save them in sd card? It will show up in gallery automatically. if it is not showing in gallery you can call the following to call implicitly after downloading the images to sd card.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Answer (score 0):

save image in sdcard. But after this, you will not be able to see that image in gallery. To see this image, You will have to refresh sdcard using

```
broadcast(sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath())));)
```

when you will save this image.

Answer (score 0):

@Nidhi can you add image like that

```
private void addPicToGallery() {
    Intent media = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);


 //mCurrentPhotoPath is the path to image.
     File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
     Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
     media.setData(contentUri);
     this.sendBroadcast(media);
}
```